# jQuery: how to return the 'value' of an html attribute

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like:

```
<input class="button" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Abe Lincoln">
```

assuming a jQuery object

```
foo = $('input.button')
```

that consists of the above HTML, how can I extract the name from the 'value' attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
foo = $('input.button').val()
```

or you can use attr():

```
foo = $('input.button').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('input.button').val();` Docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

`.val()` will get the current value of the user's input. To get other attributes, use `.attr()`:

```
$('input.button').attr('name') // returns "submit_button"
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

---

Note, also, a warning from the `.attr` docs:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`,
>   or `disabled` state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method.

i.e., don't use `$('input.button').attr('checked')`, rather `$('input.button').prop('checked')`.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the value of any attribute then you can use jQuery's [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```
var output = $('input.button').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = $('input.button');
var val =foo.val();
```